# Check if file exists on server and return a value

Tags: android, multithreading, file-io

I want to check if the file exist on server and if exists set boolean value to true and use it's value out of the thread.

it's my code:

```
new Thread() {

    public void run() {

  try {
     HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
     // note : you may also need
     //HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)

     HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
     con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
     if( (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) ) {
        fileExists = true;
     }
     else {
        fileExists = false;
     }
          catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           log.d("FILE_EXISTS", "false");;
       }
         }
  }.start();
```

But the Boolean is false after passing this code and Im sure that file exists on the server!!

Comment: Have you declared fileExists as volatile?

Comment: and boolean not Boolean

Comment: I have no idea about volatile!

Comment: volatile boolean fileExists = false;  If you don't declare a variable as volatile in a multi-threaded application then the value is not guaranteed to be consistent across threads.

Comment: I add volatile boolean fileExists = false; but the boolean value is not true out of the thread. my did a log and it shows true!!

Comment: You are checking the value of fileExists probably on the wrong place/time. You can only check the value when the thread has finished. How do you know you only check after the thread has finished? What do you mean with `out of the thread`?